# Projection matrix + world plane ~> Homography from image plane to world plane

Tags: projective-geometry, homography

I think I have my wires crossed on this, it should be quite easy.

I have a projection matrix from world coordinates to image coordinates (4D homogeneous to 3D homgeneous), and therefore I also have the inverse projection matrix from image coordinates to world "rays".

I want to project points of the image back onto a plane within the world (which is given of course as 4D homogeneous vector). The needed homography should be uniquely identified, yet I can not figure out how to compute it.

Of course I could also intersect the back-projected rays with the world plane, but this seems not a good way, knowing that there MUST be a homography doing this for me.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: *"Of course I could also intersect the back-projected rays with the world plane"* Why not just do that with a general equation for a plane?

Comment: It is my current solution and it is working, but I think finding the direct homography would be more elegant. In addition the matrix multiplication should be faster in MatLab.