# Project points from a plane to the camera plane

Tags: python, projective-geometry

Let's say I know the (x,y) coordinates of the 4 corners of the cameras view. Is there a way to calculate the pixel coordinate of a point given its (x,y) coordinate in the world? I've looked into cv2.projectPoints() but I couldn't figure out how to create the right matrices.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699760/projection-matrix-world-plane-homography-from-image-plane-to-world-plane) mentioning doing the reverse but they didn't go into much detail.

I'm doing this in python but I'm sure most methods would apply to other languages as well. Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks.

[image: Picture of the 4 corners]